# cant run npm install node-gyp exited with code:1

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I have installed node js and its dependencies and i am running 'npm install' within a nodejs project
folder. I am getting the following error. I thought it was a network issue. but my internet is fine. Not sure what the issue is at this point.

```js
fibers@2.0.2 install C:\laser\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js


C:\laser\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.23.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\laser\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN laser@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN laser@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@2.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@2.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abima\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-28T15_56_09_276Z-debug.log
```

Comment: check this out, the installation process for node-gyp https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#option-1

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: i basically had your same error, i followed option 1 and after it completed the error got away